# how to specify field name containing '.' of file type in nodejs?

Tags: javascript

I am using react-redux as front-end and nodejs as back-end.By using form tags in react-redux the field names of input elements become 'modelname.name'.I am using file input tag in my application.how can i mention the field name containing '.' of file type to retrieve the file details at nodejs ?

**backend result**

```
{ 'user.fname': 'fds',
  'user.lname': 'fsd',
  'user.gender': 'male',
  'user.age': '43',
  'user.email': 'ghf@mail.com',
  'user.pwd': 'g',
  'user.confpwd': 'g',
  'user.status': 'Online',
  'user.confirmation': 'on' }
{ 'user.uploadContent': 
   { name: 'Screenshot from 2018-03-08 17-27-22.png',
     data: <Buffer 89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a 00 00 00 0d 49 48 44 52 00 00 05 56 00 00 03 00 08 02 00 00 00 40 5c ab 95 00 00 00 03 73 42 49 54 08 08 08 db e1 4f e0 00 00 ... >,
     encoding: '7bit',
     truncated: false,
     mimetype: 'image/png',
     md5: 'a83b8faf7909d556bc17169b209f5543',
     mv: [Function: mv] } }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you get an object such as this one on the back end:

```
formData: {
  'modelname.name': 'value'
}
```

To access it, you can use the angle bracket notation, eg. `formData['modelname.name']` instead of `formData.key` as usual.

Hope I helped!